# How to select a specific row from ClipBoard

Tags: delphi, copy, clipboard, paste

I have copy text from multiple TEdit using sLineBreak, and I would like to paste the clipboard row by row in other TEdit

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a TStringList to convert Clipboard.AsText to a list of separate lines. Then get individual lines from the string list using the strings index. For example:

```
procedure TForm21.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Text := clipboard.AsText;
    Edit1.Text := sl[2];
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```